# Detect Draggable Handle on Droppable Element in jQuery

Tags: drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I've defined a draggable element (`menu`) and its handle, which is nested (`menuHandle`).

There's a droppable element elsewhere. Apparently, setting the droppable's `accept` property to `menuHandle` does not work and it must be set to `menu`.

How can a droppable element accept a draggable handle instead of the entire draggable element?